# Need help re-installing a windows service without rebooting

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a new Windows Service Project in Visual Studio 2010 and added a little bit of code to output information to the Event Viewer.  Every time I make a little change I do the following:

1. Stop the service
2. Uninstall the service
3. Close my services window.
4. Make sure there are no instances of mmc running in task manager
5. Re-install the service

When I try step 5, it fails install.  If I try to uninstall it again, I get "This service has been marked for deletion".  I am not able to install the service again without a reboot.  This is very inconvenient.

I have search online and that is my reason for including steps 3 and 4.  This just has not worked for me.  The problem has to be on my computer because I have no problem uninstalling and installing the service on a VM instance.

I am on Windows 7 and writing my service in C# on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Did you try closing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to uninstall the service for every little change. You simply need to make sure that the service is fully stopped and you can overwrite the DLL(s) that make up the service and then start it up again.

Comment: +1 that saves a lot of time and pain :) except if you want to change things like it's event log name or service account (you can do it from service manager, unless you're testing the actual installation process)

Comment: Wow!  Didn't that just speed up development time!  I'd still like to know what is preventing the uninstall/install since it used to work when I created services; however, that seems kind of useless now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of goind through the manual process describe run the following from the command prompt:

sc delete [service name]

Comment: I have tried to delete that way in a separate instance.  Still the same problem.  Seems like something is locking the service from completing the delete process.  I just don't know how to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

sc delete doesn't delete event sources from registry, and your service's log is still there. run regedit and find entries with your service name - if there's still results for the eventlog, you can delete them. Should help, especcially if your service has the same name as your eventlog

And there is sometimes this strange behaviour of the services window. I noticed that if it's open when you try to uninstall the service, it'll only be scheduled for deleting, not actually deleted. So switch your point 2 and 3.

also, you can make .bat file and call installutil.exe there to uninstall your service. Only it have to be the correct installutil.exe - there can be more than one on your machine: for different frameworks, x86 x64... It have to be correct for your configuration.

And remember to keep that services window closed unless you really need it :)

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 2.0 on x64 system
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Uninstalling WindowsService...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /u "path to your service"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the service key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.