# Win7 Services Control Manager does not install my service

Tags: c, service, windows-7, inno-setup

I have a C program that (from command line) is able to install and uninstall itself as a Service using SCManager function calls in WinSvc.h.

This functionality is used in an Inno-Setup installer that calls the Service Control Manager to stop the service, then calls the C program to uninstall itself as a service, then the installer installs a lot of files and calls the C program to install itself as a service again.

The problem is that some times the C program is not installed as a service when I check the Services GUI, even though no error messages were being reported by the SCManager.

It is as if the SCManager in Win7 has a mind of its own, maybe delaying operations or something. The result is that I get no errors, but my C program is not installed as a service.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Are you properly waiting for the service to be stopped ? Besides, add some debugging into it. As you find out, you have no way to see what's happening inside.

Comment: Yes I am. The installer calls the stop service command and then waits until the .exe file is no longer loaded, before continuing to uninstall.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't get this question at all. If you would have some logging, you would find the reason why the service is not installed. Every Windows SC function returns a value and provides a way to get extended information in case of failure. So, if you were having this sort of debugging, you would know the reason already, I guess.

Comment: Three things come to my mind:
1. Are you running the installer with elevated user rights?
2. Have you tried rebooting the computer after install/reinstall/upgrading? 
3. If you are upgrading do you really have to uninstall the service? If the service name doesn't change nor the exe it points to then it should be enough to stop the service, update and then restart the service again? See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764203/need-help-re-installing-a-windows-service-without-rebooting

Comment: It appears that a service is disabled when being uninstalled, and the service can stay disabled for a period of time until SCM decides to actually uninstall the service. During this time any new installation of the service is accepted by SCM (no errors) but the install command is not carried out, and the service then disappears a little later.

Comment: Why do you need to uninstall? Isn't stopping sufficient?

Comment: I could go that way, but I'm interested in knowing what the problem is.